# Problem installing Ubuntu 16.10 from USB Stick

Tags: system-installation, 16.10, usb-installation

After recent problems I tried to download Ubuntu 16.10 manually and tried to install it using a USB stick. The USB stick is formatted to fat32 and is of 32GB.
But while trying to install it I get this this error and happens in loop.

```
[6.227360]    scsi host6: runtime PM trying to activate child device host6 but parent (2-1.6:1.0) is not active
[7.435522]    sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found
[7.435574]    sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[12.430305]   blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector0
[19.241646]   blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector0
[19.241648]   buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
```

And this is in loop. Please check [the image of the problem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klERK.jpg) Solution to this will be appreciated. [My PC configuration can be seen here.](http://www.saumyainc.com/hardware_info.htm) 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please edit your question and add a description of your computer: - Brand name and model
- CPU
- RAM (size)
- graphics chip/card
- wifi chip/card.  Also, please tell us which tool you used to create the USB boot drive. Finally, please check with *md5sum* that the download was good: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: What Operating system are you currently or were u previously running?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the error messages you get for installs really aren't that helpful.
Also, not every USB stick actually works as a bootable medium - it depends on the make you are using. FAT32 is what you need and 32 GB is plenty.

Did you try the Linux Live USB Creator? You can download it [here](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a new bootable USB after reformatting the stick.

Your PC Configuration link wasn't visible.  What CPU is it in the machine? Sometimes you have to force the processor to use physical address extension (PAE) if it's very old (like the Pentium M 780 i'm using on this machine).

The other, possible easier, option is to burn a rewritable DVD with the .iso file for Ubuntu 16.10 using a burning utility (e.g. IMGBURN, xfburn) on a slow speed (4x). Then set the bios to boot off the DVD.